# Non-differentiability of the set of optima of certain optimization problems

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be compact and say the function $f \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ is locally Lipschitz continuous. Say $\mathcal{X}$ is the set of all solutions of the following optimization problem:
\begin{align}
\min \quad & f(x) \\
\mathtt{s.t.} \quad x & \in X
\end{align}

Are there any general results that establish the differentiability of $f$ at points in the set $\mathcal{X}$?

For example, I'm looking for conditions under which we can explicitly say that the function is not differentiable at any point in $\mathcal{X}$. A simple example of this is if the function $f$ is the absolute value function. Modifications to any of the assumptions made are allowed.